# Creating a model for a webshop

Tags: machine-learning, modeling, prior

I'm going to create a Multi-armed bandit algorithm to handle recommendations for a large scale webshop. I'm going to use Thompson sampling (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson_sampling) and would like to get some pointers towards a good way to make prior distributions.

I've thought about what to classify, and in the beginning I was thinking of using:

```
Price
Category
Gender
```

I guess I would just like to be hinted in the right direction, since it was a long time since I read a statistical course.